# Not able to get admin consent and access token using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-calendar

I want to build a sample application which can read the calendar of outlook account either live or office365 using Microsoft graph API.

The case I am trying to implement is [Microsoft Graph : Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

1. I created a personal account on outlook live.
2. Registered an application on Azure Portal.
3. Next step was to get admin consent.
4. For Admin consent I tried to hit :

   https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent
   ?client_id=clientId
   &state=state
   &redirect_uri=redirect-uri

Getting error :

**We are unable to issue tokens from this API version for a Microsoft account. Please contact the application vendor as they need to use version 2.0 of the protocol to support this.**

Comment: Are you sure you got the error when getting admin consent? Did you login with the admin account?

Comment: @JoyWang I created account on [Outlook live](https://outlook.live.com/owa/) so in this case there will not be any admin. But in steps mentioned in the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) I must get admin consent in order to get access token.

Comment: You login the portal with your outlook account to create the application as the reply mentioned?

Comment: Yes I logged in to the Azure portal using same personal account  and registered my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you used your personal account to register the application on Azure portal, you can only [get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user). You can only get access to the sign in user calendar.(both personal accounts and o365 accounts)

[image]

**Authorization request**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={your_client_id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

Then you can use the code you got in the url to [get the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token).